# Handling absolute urls in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, electron

this is my firs project with electron and nodejs
I need to load a specific folder in my electron application
the final structure should be like:

Myapp.app

folder-contents

MyApp must read contents from folder-contents directory

```
import httpServer from './server'

function createMainWindow() {
  const window = new BrowserWindow()

  if (isDevelopment) {
    window.webContents.openDevTools()
  }

  window.loadURL(`http://localhost:18081/${app.getAppPath()}/folder-contents/`)
}
```

in **server.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 18081;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(process.cwd()));
app.set('port', PORT);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, "127.0.0.1");

module.exports = app;
```

In my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "compile": "electron-webpack",
    "dist": "yarn compile && electron-builder",
    "dist:dir": "yarn dist --dir -c.compression=store -c.mac.identity=null",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
```

launching npm run dist --mac and open myapp.app i get this error
Cannot GET /folder-contents/

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can add your files to a folder name public and inside that you can have all your static files stored and then you need to call it in your app.js like:
app.use(express.static('public') //Public is the name of the folder and then you might be able to use all of your static files presented in that folder in your project if this didn't clear you here's a refrence if i am wrong and you get the correct answer else where please correct me.Thank you.
[This is an express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem is that i need to serve files located (for example ) in Library/Application Support/MyApp/Contents or a different location like Deskop  or Documents

Comment: Refer to the express documentation i refereed to above that might be useful in your case